# Find least usage drive across all Stornext mounted drives before write any content

Tags: linux, load, load-balancing, drive, san

Requirement: 6 SAN / Stornext drive volumes(equal in size - 100TB each) mounted to a Linux server.

10 applications with 100+ read/write operations possible concurrently.

Trying to write a centralized service component(volume administration service) to decide the best drive to perform before any write operations. This is to balance the load content across all the drives.

My approach:

- Check disk usage of each volume
- Reserve XXXX MB for each request by volume
- Decide the least capacity volume after adding reserved volume size + actual disk usage of the volume
- Release the reserved volume as soon as volume starts writing.

Caveat:

- Reserve XXXX MB may not provide to calculate the accurate size when concurrent write operations.
- It's actually feed contents unsure of size on write operations.

Comment: Just curious why do you need to have separate volumes?